# Can we use domain model at UI layer in MVVM pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

Can I use domain model at UI layer instead of view model in some of the views. If No. Why shouldn't I use?

Comment: You can, but you won't be following the MVVM patterns full intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are exposing some model objects in a list to an ItemsSource, I think this completely fine.  I generally take the approach to only wrap a model such as this in a ViewModel when:

1. I need custom formatting of a property that seems cleaner to do in a ViewModel than using IValueConverter
2. I need to put a method/ICommand on the object

I wouldn't do it if the models are somehow bound to a View not in an ItemsSource such as a Window or UserControl, however.  If you are finding you have ViewModels that don't have very many properties or methods/ICommand, then you need to merge several into the one ViewModel.